# Issue installing Unity.Interception nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, unity-container

I am trying to install the Unity.Interception nuget package for a Web API project in Visual Studio 15. I already have installed and have been using Unity 4.0.1, however I get a strange error when trying to install Unity.Interception (I covered up local file system paths with {} and an abbreviated route name).

Output from Package Manager :

```
Installing Unity.Interception 4.0.1.
Adding package 'Unity.Interception.4.0.1' to folder '{projectpath}\packages'
Added package 'Unity.Interception.4.0.1' to folder '{projectpath}\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Unity.Interception.4.0.1 : Unity [4.0.1, )' does not exist in project '{projectname}'
Removing package 'Unity.Interception.4.0.1 : Unity [4.0.1, )' from folder '{projectpath}\packages'
Removed package 'Unity.Interception.4.0.1 : Unity [4.0.1, )' from folder '{projectpath}\packages'
Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration'.
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seemed a simple reboot of Visual Studio resolved this issue for me.